# Classic ASP do while, move to next loop in advance

Tags: loops, vbscript, asp-classic

I was wondering if there is any way you can start over in a do until-loop earlier than its ordinary loop end point.

Non-working example to try and explain what I want:

```
do until RS.eof
  ...
amount = RS("product_amount")
response.write(amount)
if amount > 5 then
    rs.movenext
    loop
end if
  ...
rs.movenext
loop
```

The ...'s symbolizes more code.

And yes, I understand I can just put an if-tag around the bottom code to skip to the end loop, but I want to try and keep it as clean as possible without a lot of nested if-statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The only thing you can use is `Exit Do` which will exit the `do` entirely.  You will have to rely on `if...then`s to keep things separated like you are currently doing.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Accepted as an answer, because it answers my question about the possibility, or lack thereof, to go to the next loop in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just invert your condition.  Do your stuff in the IF END IF code, and continue after if condition is false.

```
do until RS.eof
      ...
    amount = RS("product_amount")
    response.write(amount)
    if not (amount > 5) then
        ...
    end if

    rs.movenext
loop
```

Comment: You can't use `Goto <label>` in VBScript it isn't valid syntax.

Comment: Would have been lovely if the second alternative actually worked in ASP Classic. And the first alternative is pretty much what I wanted to avoid, having long if statements. Especially if I want to hypothetically restart the loop on more than one point in the "bottom ... code".

I understand you can use if-statements to block out the code, I was merely wondering if it's possible to restart a loop.

Comment: If your if statement is too long, may be it's time to put in a sub or function?

Comment: It's a database info-gathering loop that I want to be able to restart and go to the next record at different points. The question was if it was possible to restart a loop early, or if somewhat tangled if-statements is the only way to go in ASP classic. Functions wouldn't make the loop better overviewable in my case. Unfortunately I can't post the actual code, which is why I made the question into more of a hypothetical scenario.